# Graphviz Dot : Mixing clusters and nodes causes dot to crash

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to do create an overview a process, and for 1 subprocess in parallel with 1 task, I want the following graph :

```
digraph cluster0 {
    graph [compound=true label=0]
        I_0 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        E_0 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]

    subgraph cluster1 {
      graph [compound=true label=subprocess1]
        I_1 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        E_1 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        I_1 -> t111 -> t112 -> t113
        I_1 -> t121 -> t122 -> t123
        I_1 -> t131 -> t132 -> t133
        t113 -> E_1 [style=invis]
        t123 -> E_1 [style=invis]
        t133 -> E_1 [style=invis]
    }
    I_0 -> I_1 [lhead=cluster1]
    E_1 -> E_0 [ltail=cluster1 style=invis]

    I_0 -> task1
    task1 -> E_0 [style=invis]
}
```

Running

```
dot -Tpng process.dot -o process.png
```

yields the following expected output : 
[Dot output from code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac8MU.png)

However, if I try to add another subprocess in parallel to the existing subprocess and task, I get a pop-up notifying that dot crashed :

```
digraph cluster0 {
  graph [compound=true label=0]
    I_0 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
    E_0 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]

    subgraph cluster1 {
      graph [compound=true label=subprocess1]
        I_1 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        E_1 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        I_1 -> t111 -> t112 -> t113
        I_1 -> t121 -> t122 -> t123
        I_1 -> t131 -> t132 -> t133
        t113 -> E_1 [style=invis]
        t123 -> E_1 [style=invis]
        t133 -> E_1 [style=invis]
    }
    I_0 -> I_1 [lhead=cluster1]
    E_1 -> E_0 [ltail=cluster1 style=invis]

    subgraph cluster2 {
      graph [compound=true label=subprocess2]
        I_2 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        E_2 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
        I_2 -> t211 -> t212 -> t213
        I_2 -> t221 -> t222 -> t223
        I_2 -> t231 -> t232 -> t233
        t213 -> E_2 [style=invis]
        t223 -> E_2 [style=invis]
        t233 -> E_2 [style=invis]
    }
    I_0 -> I_2 [lhead=cluster2]
    E_2 -> E_0 [ltail=cluster2 style=invis]

    I_0 -> task1
    task1 -> E_0 [style=invis]
}
```

Am I doing something illegal, or something that I shouldn't be doing? Haven't been able to find any help about this behavior elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I_2 [label="" height=0 shape=none style=invis width=0]
```

It seems that you can not set shape none but the label is empty. 
Try to remove the empty label or use the invisible point instead.

```
I_2 [shape=point style=invis]
```